# Exporting Hive Arrays to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive

I've been using Sqoop to move data between Hive tables and Postgresql. But apparently Sqoop does not support the Postgresql **Array** type.

I figured out a workaround when importing data from Postgresql to Hive; I use `array_to_string()` in the Sqoop `--query` parameter to transform my array to a string, and then created an external Hive table with;

```
    colelction.delim        $                   
    field.delim             ,
```

But I can't figure out a way to 'reverse' this process. Any clever workaround?